# LaravelでTwitterのシェアのURLの中に絶対パス

Tags: laravel, twitter

TwittterのOGP（シェアボタンを押して、画像、URLをシェアする）で`https://example.com/member/show/1`とそのまま絶対パスを貼れば、URLが飛ばせるのですが、
LaravelのURLでうまくURLが飛ばせません。(`url={{ route('member.show', ['id' => $id]) }}`でうまくいきません。具体的には、hashtagsやテキストは表示されますが、URLが表示されません。

＜うまくいく＞

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=シェア&url=https://example.com/member/show/1&hashtags=blog,share?" onclick="window.open(this.href,'TWwindow','width=650,height=450,menubar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');return false;">Twitter</a>
```

★URL
https://example.com/member/show/1

＜うまくいかない＞

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=シェア&url=https://example.com/member/show/1&hashtags=blog,share?" onclick="window.open(this.href,'TWwindow','width=650,height=450,menubar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');return false;">Twitter</a>
★url={{ route('member.show', ['id' => $id]) }}
```

どなたかご教示いただけませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

宣言をhrefの中に入れていますか？

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href={{ route('member.show', ['id' => $id]) }} onclick="window.open(this.href,'TWwindow','width=650,height=450,menubar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');return false;">Twitter</a>
```

もしダメならルートに名前はついていますか？

```
Route::get('/member/show'.'MemberController@show')->name('member.show');
```

みたいな感じだとは思いますが

routeはそのまま出して使用する事をしたことが無いので分かりませんがこれで行けるとおもいます